# Global Binding Style

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm wondering how can I set default UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged for all TextBox'es on window?
Is there any simpler way than using Find&Replace?

Answer (score 0):

UpdateSourceTrigger is used with Binding that is made on some property of the control, so the way you can achieve this is declare your own class derived from Binding, set UpdateSourceTrigger in that class and use this new class in markup instead of Binding class.